# Adding a database driven message to a contact form created via Django-contact-form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views, django-urls

Friends,

I am using [Django-Contact-Form](http://django-contact-form.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with my Django powered website and it is working well.

I would now like to add some text just above the form, I would rather not hard code the text but allow the message to be configured via the Django Admin screens.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

So I created the following objects:

**models.py**

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
    before_boilerplate = models.CharField(max_length = 8000)
    after_boilerplate = models.CharField(max_length = 8000)
```

**views.py**

```
def contactform(request):
    contactform_text = get_object_or_404(ContactForm, pk=1)
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'contactform_text': contactform_text})
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls')),
...
```

**contact_form.html**

```
  ...
  <article>
      <h3>{{ contactform_text.before_boilerplate }}</3>
  </article>
  ...
```

When I run the contact form I do not see the text entered via the Django Admin Screen. When I drop down into the shell and run the same commands I do see the expected text.

I can see that the problem is that within the urls.py the call is bypassing my view but unfortunately I don't know how to change it so that my view will be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't really like your approach: You've generated a model (= a database table) that will contain only *one* row (the text of the form). Instead of doing that, you can use a more generic approach, like django-constance (https://github.com/comoga/django-constance) or other similar packages (https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/) with which you can define various global settings that are saved to the database and can be edited through the django admin interface.

Also, please don't name your model `ContactForm`. You will definitely be confused later on. Use something like `ContactFormTextModel` or even `ContactFormTextKeeper`. But don't put an `*Form` suffix to something that is not a django form!

In any case, the problem with your view is that by including `contact_form.urls` you will use the default `contact_form.views.ContactFormView` (http://django-contact-form.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html) which does not know anything about the extra information you want to render in your template. So you have to pass the `contactform_text = get_object_or_404(ContactForm, pk=1)` into your View.

For completeness, I will give you two solutions, one that works but is *not* following the pythonic standards and another that works *and follows the pythonic standards*.

- The 1st one: Create a simple template tag that will output the custom contact form text and use it in your template: So, add a templatetags/contact_tags.py file in your application with the following content (or something like this):

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
import applications.models

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def render_form_text():
    return get_object_or_404(ContactForm, pk=1)
```

So now in your template you can just 
`{% load contact_tags %}`and `{% render_form_txt %}` to render the form text.

This is *not* the correct solution. You are creating a template tag that is needed only once -- instead you should pass the form_text directly to the view. How to do that ?

- Second solution: Subclass `ContactFormView` to include the required information in your context data. So, add the following in your views.py

```
from contact_form.views import ContactFormView

class FormTextContactFormView(ContactFormView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FormTextContactFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_text'] = get_object_or_404(ContactForm, pk=1)
        return context
```

Now, in your urls.py you can use the above CBV like this:

```
    url(r'^contact/', views.FormTextContactFormView.as_view(), name='contact' ),
```

and in your template you will have a context variable named `{{ form_text }}`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for, a pythonic solution. Thanks again.

Comment: The 1st solution has also its uses. For instance, if django-contact was using normal function-views instead of CBV you wouldn't be able to extend it and you'd need to copy the whole view to add the extra context variable. In this, adding the custom template tag would be the preferred solution.